# Angular 6 - HttpClient Keeping subscribe in the service but passing the result to the component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-httpclient

I have a project which contains a service (which gets the data) and a component (displays it).

I would like the keep the code to the minimum on the app.component.ts.

In the service I have:

```
getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', httpOptions).subscribe(
      result => {
        return result;
        this.theData = result;
      },
      error => {
        return error;
      }
    );
  }
```

and in my app.component.ts:

```
 getPostsFromService() {
    this.myService.getPosts();
  }
```

But of course, I need to get the result and pass it into my component but something like this wouldn't work:

```
myData;

  ...


  getPostsFromService() {
    this.myData = this.myService.getPosts();
  }
```

So, my question is, how can I do this or is it really recommended to call subscribe on my component and not in the service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In new **[HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http)**  JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed using `res.json()`

You can tell `HttpClient` the type of the response to make consuming the output easier and more obvious.

Type checking of response can be done by  using the type parameter
Create an Interface

```
export interface Idata{
  userId:number;
  Id:number;
  title:string;
  body:string;
}
```

`Http` returns an `observable` and We can tell the `HttpClient.get` to return `response` as Idata type When we use `http.get<Idata[]>(...)` then it returns the instance of `Observable<Idata[]>` type. 
**In your service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Idata} from './Idata'
@Injectable()
export class ShareService {

    constructor(private httpc:HttpClient)
    {
    }

    public getPosts():Observable<Idata[]>
    {
        return this.httpc.get<Idata[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    }
}
```

In your component `subscribe` to `Observable<Idata[]>` to get instance of Idata

```
  public data:Array<Idata>=[];
  constructor(public service:ShareService)
  {
     this.service.getPosts().subscribe(value => {
        this.data=value;
     });
  }
```

An alternative is Using `async` pipe
`AsyncPipe` accepts as an argument an `observable` or a `promise`, calls `subscribe` or attaches a then handler, then waits for the asynchronous result before passing it through to the caller.

```
public response:Observable<Idata[]>;
constructor(public service:ShareService)
{
    this.response=this.service.getPosts();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (response|async)">
  {{item.body}}
</div>
```

**[LIVEDEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbe9jg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

> my question is, how can I do this or is it really recommended to call
>   subscribe on my component and not in the service?

**[It's Good Practice to Delegate complex component logic to services](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#delegate-complex-component-logic-to-services)**

> From **Angular Style Guide**
>  Do limit logic in a component to only
>   that required for the view. All other logic should be delegated to
>   services.
>
> Do move reusable logic to services and keep components simple and
>   focused on their intended purpose.
>
> Why? Logic may be reused by multiple components when placed within a
>   service and exposed via a function.
>
> Why? Logic in a service can more easily be isolated in a unit test,
>   while the calling logic in the component can be easily mocked.
>
> Why? Removes dependencies and hides implementation details from the
>   component.
>
> Why? Keeps the component slim, trim, and focused.

Subscribing in Component lets you share a single `http` request with multiple `observers`, if you don't do so you would be violating **[DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)**
**P:S**
 To share a single `http` request for multiple `observers`, you need something like the **[share](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html)**
operator.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {share} from 'rxjs/operators'

export class dataService {

    public data$=Observable<Idata[]>
    constructor(http:HttpClient)
    {
        this.data$=this.http.get<Idata[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').pipe(share());
    }
    public getPosts():Observable<Idata[]>
    {
        return this.data$
    }
}
```

> This operator is a specialization of `publish` which creates a
>   subscription when the number of observers goes from zero to one, then
>   shares that subscription with all subsequent observers until the
>   number of observers returns to zero, at which point the subscription
>   is disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Great! You can try with Observable and Async!
In app.component

```
public posts: Observable<posts[]>
getPostsFromService() {
  this.posts = this.myService.getPosts();
}
```

And in html, you put that:

```
*ngFor="let post of posts | async"
```

And service

```
return this._http.get<posts>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', httpOptions)
```

Try that and see if worked! I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to use a service methods must return observable response like this:

```
public getPosts(): Observable<IPosts[]> {

    const data = {
      '$type' : 'ReadRequest',
      'query' : 'getPosts',
      'parameters' : {}
    };

    return this.http.post(null, data)
      .map(res => (<any>res)._body === '' ? {} : res.json().result)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.reject(error.message || 'Server error: ' + error);
  }
```

Where `IPosts` is described Interface according your response.

After in any component you can use this:

```
public posts: IPosts[] = [];
this.servicePosts.getPosts().subscribe(data => {
       this.posts = data; // Fill data from response to component variable this.post
          }, error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your component.ts should be like this.

There is no issue in your service except subscribe should be map.

```
 this.myService.getPosts().subscribe((data) => {
         this.setMyData(data);
    });

    setMyData() {
        this.myData = data;
    }
```

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote, so that I can correct myself.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this code? The question was how to resolve the response in the service layer itself and return the data to component. Hope you didn't get the question at all. Moreover, you code had error that setMyData() doesn't read the data as input.